# New Google Account not able to access script.google.com

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions, google-account

A colleague opened a new Google Account and I shared a Google Sheet with her which had scripts attached.  She gave me her temporary password so I could go through the process of authorizing her for the scripts.  I have walked lots of people through this process before, so was surprised that when I tried to trigger the script (through a button in the sheet), this happened:

First I received the expected message: "Authorization Required:  A script attached to this document needs your permission to run"

But when I hit "continue", I got a 403 error:  ACCESS DENIED. (instead of the usual dialogue box to go through the process of authorizing).

I tried to go to TOOLS > SCRIPT EDITOR and got this message:  "Can't visit this page.  It's not available for your account".  Same message when trying to go directly to script.google.com.

I have tried logging out of all other Google Accounts, but the same things happened.

HELP! :D

Comment: My guess is that admin did not enable scripts for that account.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out!  They had entered a birthdate for the account (which was a work account) with the year their organization started... which made Google think they were a minor, and therefore Scripts could not be enabled!